# Problems implementing the new GCM Client for Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I'm trying to implement the new `GCM Client` on Android following the guidelines from Google (https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client).
I'm receiving slightly different errors for two different devices. I noticed that I receive NoSuchMethodError for method getNoBackupFilesDir for both the devices.
This is the logcat for an Android 4.2.2:

```
06-08 09:01:09.920: I/dalvikvm(9138): Could not find methodandroid.app.Notification$Builder.setLocalOnly, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
06-08 09:01:09.920: W/dalvikvm(9138): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 273: Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setLocalOnly (Z)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;
06-08 09:01:09.920: D/dalvikvm(9138): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x00c2
06-08 09:01:09.920: I/dalvikvm(9138): DexOpt: access denied from Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil; to field Landroid/app/Notification;.extras
06-08 09:01:09.920: W/dalvikvm(9138): VFY: unable to resolve instance field 12
06-08 09:01:09.920: D/dalvikvm(9138): VFY: replacing opcode 0x54 at 0x00e1
06-08 09:01:09.920: E/dalvikvm(9138): Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
06-08 09:01:09.920: W/dalvikvm(9138): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 25 (Landroid/app/AppOpsManager;) in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;
06-08 09:01:09.920: D/dalvikvm(9138): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x000e
06-08 09:01:09.920: I/dalvikvm(9138): Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzh
06-08 09:01:09.920: W/dalvikvm(9138): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 528: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
06-08 09:01:09.920: D/dalvikvm(9138): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000b
06-08 09:01:09.950: I/dalvikvm(9138): Could not find method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.zzde
06-08 09:01:09.950: W/dalvikvm(9138): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2080: Landroid/support/v4/content/ContextCompat;.getNoBackupFilesDir (Landroid/content/Context;)Ljava/io/File;
06-08 09:01:09.950: D/dalvikvm(9138): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0007
06-08 09:01:09.950: W/dalvikvm(9138): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4174c930)
06-08 09:01:09.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9138): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
06-08 09:01:09.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9138): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-08 09:01:09.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9138):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
06-08 09:01:09.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9138):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
06-08 09:01:09.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9138):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
06-08 09:01:09.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9138):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
06-08 09:01:09.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9138):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
06-08 09:01:09.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9138):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-08 09:01:09.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9138):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-08 09:01:09.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9138):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-08 09:01:09.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9138): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir
06-08 09:01:09.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9138):     at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.zzde(Unknown Source)
06-08 09:01:09.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9138):     at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
06-08 09:01:09.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9138):     at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
06-08 09:01:09.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9138):     at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zza(Unknown Source)
06-08 09:01:09.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9138):     at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getInstance(Unknown Source)
06-08 09:01:09.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9138):     at com.example.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:113)
06-08 09:01:09.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9138):     at com.example.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
06-08 09:01:09.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9138):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-08 09:01:09.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9138):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-08 09:01:09.960: E/AndroidRuntime(9138):     ... 4 more
```

And this is the logcat for an Android 5.1.1:

```
06-08 09:06:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(2852): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
06-08 09:06:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(2852): Process: com.example, PID: 2852
06-08 09:06:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(2852): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-08 09:06:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
06-08 09:06:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
06-08 09:06:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
06-08 09:06:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
06-08 09:06:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
06-08 09:06:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
06-08 09:06:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
06-08 09:06:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
06-08 09:06:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(2852): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getNoBackupFilesDir(Landroid/content/Context;)Ljava/io/File; in class Landroid/support/v4/content/ContextCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat' appears in /data/app/com.example-1/base.apk)
06-08 09:06:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.zzde(Unknown Source)
06-08 09:06:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
06-08 09:06:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
06-08 09:06:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zza(Unknown Source)
06-08 09:06:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getInstance(Unknown Source)
06-08 09:06:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at it.abgsys.htms.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:113)
06-08 09:06:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at it.abgsys.htms.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
06-08 09:06:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
06-08 09:06:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-08 09:06:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(2852):     ... 4 more
```

At line 113 I have this:

```
InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(applicationContext);
```

Used here:

```
// AsyncTask to register Device in GCM Server
private void registerInBackground() {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String msg = "";

            InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(applicationContext);
            try {
                regId = instanceID.getToken(GCM_SENDER_ID,
                        GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return msg;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(regId)) {

                Toast.makeText(
                        applicationContext,
                        "Registered with GCM Server successfully.\n\n"
                                + msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e(TAG, "Registered with GCM Server successfully. RegID: " + regId);

            } else { 
                Toast.makeText(
                        applicationContext,
                        "Reg ID Creation Failed.\n\nEither you haven't enabled Internet or GCM server is busy right now. "
                        + "Make sure you enabled Internet and try registering again after some time."
                                + msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e(TAG, "Reg ID Creation Failed!!!");
            }
        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);
}
```

I correctly imported the `Google Play Services` library as described in the documentation.(https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

Has anyone encountered this errors? How can I resolve this?

Development environment used: Eclipse Kepler SR2 with ADT
If you need additional info please comment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I saw that the method `getNoBackupFilesDir` is found in android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.

Seems that the problem was that I had an old appcompat-v7 included in the project. Download with the `SDK manager` the last version of `Android Support Library` and then follow the steps for [Adding libraries with resources](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) and add the library to your application project.

Comment: Similar issue, I had an outdated android-support-v4.jar in my libs dir; updated to newer version, problem solved.

Comment: @Kurt: You are right.you should post it as an answer.

Comment: I was having this same error and thanks to your answer I found out I had appcompat-v7 and support-v4 on my app's build.gradle. Removing support-v4 did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I got this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getNoBackupFilesDir(Landroid/content/Context;)Ljava/io/File; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/util/zzx; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.util.zzx' appears in /data/data/com.crave.iapdemo/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.android.gms-play-services-basement-10.0.1_b9da1447b99cc6cbc2fa601fb84d0418780bfa55-classes.dex)
                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.zzeC(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at vodio.labs.crave.gcm.RegistrationIntentService.onHandleIntent(RegistrationIntentService.java:39)
```

in this line:

```
InstanceID.getInstance(this);
```

The solution for me was upgrading this:

```
dependencies {
    // play services
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'
}
```

into:

```
dependencies {
    // play services
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.0.1'
}
```