# Android " Could not find method android.app.Notification$Builder.setLocalOnly "

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play-services, google-analytics-firebase

I'm an Android Beginner.

Nowadays, I'm testing Google Analytics and I met the following log :

> Could not find method android.app.Notification$Builder.setLocalOnly, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza

what is mean and what I have to do?

Answer (score 3):

`setLocalOnly` is available on **API Level 20 and above**. May I know that do you include Android Support Library v4 or AppCompat v7 to your app yet? It might helps. I believe that Google Play Services will use NotificaionCompat provided in Support Library v4 if available.

Comment: Hello. I got the same error. I included AppCompat v7. So do i really have to use AppCompat v4?

Answer (score 0):

There were changes to android.support.v4 and appcompat-v7. Make sure you have the latest ones. This may be similar to:
[Problems implementing the new GCM Client for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30705235/problems-implementing-the-new-gcm-client-for-android)