# Google map is showing up blank, app throws "Could not find method" exceptions

Tags: android, google-maps

I had Google Maps V2 integrated with my app and it was working perfectly fine. I am facing this issue from today - Exceptions on methods not found and a blank checkered screen instead of map. Please let me know how to fix this, appreciate your help.

```
04-25 01:48:47.711: I/dalvikvm(28543): Could not find method android.app.Notification$Builder.setLocalOnly, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
04-25 01:48:47.711: W/dalvikvm(28543): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 332: Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setLocalOnly (Z)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;
04-25 01:48:47.711: D/dalvikvm(28543): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x00c2
04-25 01:48:47.711: I/dalvikvm(28543): Could not find method android.app.AppOpsManager.checkPackage, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
04-25 01:48:47.711: W/dalvikvm(28543): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 203: Landroid/app/AppOpsManager;.checkPackage (ILjava/lang/String;)V
04-25 01:48:47.711: D/dalvikvm(28543): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0010
04-25 01:48:47.711: I/dalvikvm(28543): Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzh
04-25 01:48:47.711: W/dalvikvm(28543): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 635: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
04-25 01:48:47.711: D/dalvikvm(28543): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000b
04-25 01:48:47.721: I/zzy(28543): Making Creator dynamically
04-25 01:48:47.751: I/dalvikvm(28543): Could not find method android.app.Notification$Builder.setLocalOnly, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.os.b
04-25 01:48:47.751: W/dalvikvm(28543): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 142: Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setLocalOnly (Z)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate. There were changes to android.support.v4 and appcompat-v7. Try to download with the SDK manager the last version of Android Support Library and then follow the steps for Adding libraries with resources and add the library to your application project as stated in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31002765/android-could-not-find-method-android-app-notificationbuilder-setlocalonly).

Comment: Thanks. I tried that. Now the issue is that I get a blank screen if the API Key is correct and an authentication error if I induce a wrong key deliberately.

Answer (score 0):

> Now the issue is that I get a blank screen if the API Key is correct
>   and an authentication error if I induce a wrong key deliberately

Here's things you can try given that you have the correct API Key:

1. Enable the permissions on your Manifest.

   ```
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
       <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
   ```
2. Make sure you provided correct package name from your Manifest as well as SHA1 certificate fingerprint in your GDC.
3. Set Google Maps API to Enabled.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for that info, yes I have done both and have even got a test project to work fine. Just that my app which used to work well, has stopped showing the map even though I have not done any change. Really strange.