# Implementing GCM on Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-support-library

I wanted to add GCM in to my app, so I first followed the tutorial in this link : http://hmkcode.com/android-google-cloud-messaging-tutorial/

But I couldn't send any messages from server because it always returned InvalidRegistration, even if i just copy paste the Registration I get in my app, which is generated by gcm.register() method. So I looked in official page

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

says that register() is deprecated and InstanceID API should be used. Now I followed the instruction from the page. I am getting the following error:

```
 07-05 14:49:17.066: E/AndroidRuntime(25823): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
07-05 14:49:17.066: E/AndroidRuntime(25823): Process: com.example.studentapp, PID: 25823
07-05 14:49:17.066: E/AndroidRuntime(25823): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-05 14:49:17.066: E/AndroidRuntime(25823):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
07-05 14:49:17.066: E/AndroidRuntime(25823):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
07-05 14:49:17.066: E/AndroidRuntime(25823):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
07-05 14:49:17.066: E/AndroidRuntime(25823):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
07-05 14:49:17.066: E/AndroidRuntime(25823):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-05 14:49:17.066: E/AndroidRuntime(25823):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-05 14:49:17.066: E/AndroidRuntime(25823):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-05 14:49:17.066: E/AndroidRuntime(25823):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
07-05 14:49:17.066: E/AndroidRuntime(25823): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getNoBackupFilesDir(Landroid/content/Context;)Ljava/io/File; in class Landroid/support/v4/content/ContextCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat' appears in /data/app/com.example.studentapp-2/base.apk)
07-05 14:49:17.066: E/AndroidRuntime(25823):    at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.zzde(Unknown Source)
07-05 14:49:17.066: E/AndroidRuntime(25823):    at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
07-05 14:49:17.066: E/AndroidRuntime(25823):    at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
07-05 14:49:17.066: E/AndroidRuntime(25823):    at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zza(Unknown Source)
07-05 14:49:17.066: E/AndroidRuntime(25823):    at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getInstance(Unknown Source)
07-05 14:49:17.066: E/AndroidRuntime(25823):    at com.example.studentapp.register_gcm.doInBackground(register_gcm.java:41)
07-05 14:49:17.066: E/AndroidRuntime(25823):    at com.example.studentapp.register_gcm.doInBackground(register_gcm.java:1)
07-05 14:49:17.066: E/AndroidRuntime(25823):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
07-05 14:49:17.066: E/AndroidRuntime(25823):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-05 14:49:17.066: E/AndroidRuntime(25823):    ... 4 more
```

So I followed another question similar to this in the below link:

[Problems implementing the new GCM Client for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30705235/problems-implementing-the-new-gcm-client-for-android)

I have revision 19.1 revision of support library and i couldn't upgrade further using the sdk manager.

my code for registration is

```
package com.example.studentapp;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;
import com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID;

public  class register_gcm extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, String> {


     GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
     Context c;
     String regid;
     String PROJECT_NUMBER = "981827135766";






                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                     String msg = "";
                        try {
                          /*  if (gcm == null) {
                                gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(c);
                            }
                            regid = gcm.register(PROJECT_NUMBER);
                            msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;
                            Log.d("GCM",  msg + regid);
                            */
                            InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(c);
                            String token = instanceID.getToken(PROJECT_NUMBER,
                                    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
                            Log.d("GCM",  token);

                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();

                        }
                        return regid;
                    }


                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {

                      try {

                            FileOutputStream fos = c.openFileOutput("register_status.zaf", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                            fos.write(regid.getBytes());

                            fos.close();

                        } catch (Exception e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }




                }



}
```

so how do I solve this?

Comment: The tutorial and example here worked for me https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start

Comment: i am following the tutorial on the given link. my problem lies with the support library

Comment: Try to clone their example and see if it works. The example worked for me. Perhaps you'll need to update google play on your phone but the example gives a message if you need that

Comment: I use Eclipse ADT. And that project was built on Android Studio.

Comment: What they do in the code does not depend on the ide

Comment: Check your [build path](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res). There could be duplicates or an older version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind,

What I did is, install the latest ADT plugin on newer version of Eclipse and updated the support library and changed the build target to API 22