# Android: GoogleCloudMessaging token id not returned

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I want get token id by GCM

> My code :

```
InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
String token = instanceID.getToken("xxxx", GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
Log.i("error", "GCM Registration Token: " + token);
```

> Error Log :

```
04-29 18:20:52.275: E/AndroidRuntime(7382): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[RegIntentService]
04-29 18:20:52.275: E/AndroidRuntime(7382): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir
04-29 18:20:52.275: E/AndroidRuntime(7382):     at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.zzeb(Unknown Source)
04-29 18:20:52.275: E/AndroidRuntime(7382):     at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
04-29 18:20:52.275: E/AndroidRuntime(7382):     at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
04-29 18:20:52.275: E/AndroidRuntime(7382):     at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zza(Unknown Source)
04-29 18:20:52.275: E/AndroidRuntime(7382):     at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getInstance(Unknown Source)
04-29 18:20:52.275: E/AndroidRuntime(7382):     at com.app.network.RegistrationIntentService.onHandleIntent(RegistrationIntentService.java:43)
04-29 18:20:52.275: E/AndroidRuntime(7382):     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
04-29 18:20:52.275: E/AndroidRuntime(7382):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-29 18:20:52.275: E/AndroidRuntime(7382):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
04-29 18:20:52.275: E/AndroidRuntime(7382):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

How can fixed it ?

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30705235/problems-implementing-the-new-gcm-client-for-android

Comment: Thanks, I updated android support library but not work

Comment: Can you post your gradle?